# Cannot open Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, jupyter

I have installed Jupyter notebook using pip on my Ubuntu 18.04. It is apparently installed correctly, since when i type in terminal:

```
which jupyter
```

it returns

```
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

But when I run `jupyter notebook` in terminal it shows the following error (both with and without `sudo`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1379, in init_webapp
self.jinja_environment_options,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 270, in init_settings
nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1066, in nbextensions_path
from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
from .core.application import Application
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
from IPython.core import ultratb
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
from IPython.utils import path as util_path
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
from IPython.utils.process import system
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
import pexpect
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using python version 3.7. How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: I have no problem with installation. It is the problem when i try to run the notebook from terminal.

Comment: The PIP command matters: `pip` is for Python 2 and `pip3` is for Python 3. Also, [jupyter is available in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jupyter&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) since 18.04 (bionic), so installing via APT should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I installed Jupyter notebook only without installing anaconda. It should have worked. But for some reasons beyond my knowledge I wasn't able to run it.

So, as recommended on [the official page](http://jupyter.org/install#installing-jupyter-using-anaconda), I installed Jupyter using anaconda, and since doing so I am now able to successfully run Jupyter notebook using the command `jupyter notebook`.

Although the problem has now been solved in an alternative way I'd still like to know what my problem was initially, and how I could have solved it.